# Matrix generation in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran77

The problem: I need to generate a M*N matrix, where M is for rows, N is for columns.
Elements of this matrix should be like (i-1.0)*N+j.
This code doesn't work and I can't understand why.
I use Compaq Visual Fortran 6.

I except that this code must generate a matrix. After generation the matrix should be printed like

1.0 2.0 3.0

4.0 5.0 6.0

as for 3*2 matrix.

Now this code simply doesn't work, showing me a cpoule of Windows Executing Errors.

```
INTEGER M, N, I, J
COMMON /BLK1/ MATA (256, 256)
READ (7, 100) M
READ (7, 100) N
100 FORMAT (I3)
CALL MATGEN (M, N)
DO 90003 I = 1, M
DO 90004 J = 1, N
WRITE (8, 101) MATA(I, J)
101 FORMAT (F8.1, ' ', \)
90004 CONTINUE
WRITE (8, 102)
102 FORMAT (/, /)
90003 CONTINUE
END



SUBROUTINE MATGEN (M, N)
REAL DUM
INTEGER I, J
COMMON /BLK1/ MATA (256, 256)
DUM = 1.0
DO 90001 I = 1, M
DO 90002 J = 1, N
MATA (I, J) = DUM + 1.0
90002 CONTINUE
90001 CONTINUE
RETURN
END

COMMON BLK1
REAL MATA (256, 256)
END
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified why the code doesn't work. What are you expecting it to do? And what does it do now?

Comment: you dont open unit 7

Comment: `implicit none` will be a good thing for you.  As well as that issue, note that your assignment for `mata(i,j)` does not in any way depend on `i` or `j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- The program does not really start (in the code below this is `PROGRAM TEST`)
- `MATA` is (implicitly) an integer. I added the declaration. Please use `IMPLICIT NONE` in the future!
- There is some weird code at the end that doesn't really belong there...
- As francescalus noted, the assignment is not incremented, so `MATA` is filled with `2`.
- My version of `gfortran` does not accept the backslash to inhibit the line break. I had to use `$`. See [here](http://jblevins.org/log/array-write) for details.
- Agentp remarked that you do not open unit seven for input. I changed that lines to read from `STDIN` instead.
- Indentation does not hurt!

```
      PROGRAM TEST
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER M, N, I, J
      REAL MATA
      COMMON /BLK1/ MATA(256, 256)
      WRITE(*,*) 'Please enter M:'
      READ (*, 100) M
      WRITE(*,*) 'Please enter N:'
      READ (*, 100) N
100   FORMAT (I3)

      CALL MATGEN (M, N)
      DO 90003 I = 1, M
        DO 90004 J = 1, N
          WRITE (8, 101) MATA(I, J)

101   FORMAT (F8.1, ' ', $)
90004   CONTINUE
        WRITE (8, 102)
102   FORMAT (/, /)
90003 CONTINUE
      END

      SUBROUTINE MATGEN (M, N)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER M, N
      REAL DUM
      INTEGER I, J
      REAL MATA
      COMMON /BLK1/ MATA(256, 256)
      DUM = 0.0
      DO 90001 I = 1, M
        DO 90002 J = 1, N
          DUM = DUM + 1.
          MATA (I, J) = DUM
90002   CONTINUE
90001 CONTINUE
      RETURN
      END
```

This results in:

```
$ ./a.out 
 Please enter M:
2
 Please enter N:
3

$ cat fort.8 
     1.0      2.0      3.0 


     4.0      5.0      6.0
```

Comment: for the record the backslash appears to be an intel extension.  Note the `$` is also an extension, though more common I think.   Unless you really need to work with an antique compiler, try `advance=no` instead.

Comment: @agentp `advance=no` has been added in Fortran 95 and is not available for FORTRAN 77. Unfortunately, inhibiting the line feed is not defined in the FORTRAN 77 Standard and `$`, the backslash, and some other line endings are used by the different compilers.

Comment: right, my point is sometimes folks think just because they are working with some old code they have to avoid modern constructs even though their compiler supports them.